# Can I use Action<T> to perform a recursive search and return an IEnumerable of a specified property?

Tags: linq, generics, c#-4.0, action

I've written the following code for retrieving the `StructureId`s from an `IEnumerable<Structure>`:

```
Action<Structure> recurse = null;
List<int> structureIds = new List<int>();
recurse = (r) =>
{
    structureIds.Add(r.StructureId);
    r.Children.ForEach(recurse);
};

IEnumerable<Structure> structures = GetStructures();
structures.ForEach(recurse);
```

I'd really like to make this generic so I can use it with any IEnumerable, i.e. something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TType> GetPropertyValues<TType, TPropertyType>(
    this IEnumerable<TType> this, <Property Declaration>)
{
    // Generic version of the above code?
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Can it be done? Yes. Would anyone still be able to understand your code? No.

Comment: @Steven - See the accepted answer. It's very understandable and works brilliantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Action` isn't very Linq'ish.  How about `Func` instead?  (Untested code)

```
public static IEnumerable<TProp> RecurseSelect<TSource, TProp>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  Func<TSource, TProp> propertySelector,
  Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> childrenSelector
)
{
  foreach(TSource x in source)
  {
    yield return propertySelector(x);
    IEnumerable<TSource> children = childrenSelector(x);
    IEnumerable<TProp> values = children.RecurseSelect(propertySelector, childrenSelector);
    foreach(TProp y in values)
    {
      yield return y;
    }
  }
}
```

And then

```
IEnumerable<Structure> structures = GetStructures();
IEnumerable<int> structureIds = structures.RecurseSelect(
  s => s.StructureId,
  s => s.Children);
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect (as is). I knew it could be done, thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not adding each item to a list, you're adding the a property of each item.  That property will only be available for a `Structure`, and not any other type you might reuse the code with.

You also don't have a mechanism for getting the children of your other classes. (the `r.Children` property you use).

Your two solutions would be to use interfaces (that is, define `IHasChildren` and `IGetProperty`) that could be used as base types for a simple algorithm, or you could pass in functions to your method that allow this to be more freely calculated.  For example, your method signature might need to be this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TPropertyType> GetPropertyValues<TType, TPropertyType>
        (this IEnumerable<TType> rootItem, Func<TType, IEnumerable<TType>> getChildren, Func<TType, TPropertyType> getIdValue)
```

... but that's not going to be very pretty!